# Multiple attachments in singleemail class

Tags: apex, email, controller, attachment, singleemailmessage

I want to attach two (2) pdf files in a single email. Please find my below code which is doing attachment for only one of them. Can someone please help me here?

**Controller snippet:**

```
PageReference pdf = Page.CompIncidentTransactionsAttachment;
            pdf.getParameters().put('Ids',Ids ); //
            pdf.setRedirect(true);//false

            Blob b = pdf.getContent();
            Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();

            efa.setFileName('ComplianceIncidentReport.pdf');
            efa.setBody(b);                   
            email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});        



            PageReference pdf1 = Page.CompIncidentTransactionsAttachmentSample;
            pdf1.getParameters().put('Ids',Ids ); //
            pdf1.setRedirect(true);//false

            Blob b1 = pdf1.getContent();
            Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa1 = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();

            efa1.setFileName('SampleIncidentReport.pdf');
            efa1.setBody(b1);                   
            email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa1});  
             email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});
```

Comment: SFDC_Learner... I think you can close this ans..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in your code, the parameter of the method :
`setFileAttachments()`
is an array of the class: `Messaging.EmailFileAttachment`:

```
 email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});
```

If you want to add an another attachment, you can instanciate it like you dit it previously:

```
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa2 = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
efa2.setFileName('ComplianceIncidentReport_2.pdf');
efa2.setBody(b);
```

And add it to the array:

```
email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa, efa2});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
    Integer numAtts=[SELECT count() FROM attachment WHERE parentid=: account.Id];

    List<Attachment> allAttachment = new List<Attachment>();
    allAttachment = [SELECT Id, Name, ContentType, Body FROM Attachment WHERE parentid =: account.Id];

    List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> efaList = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();


    if(numAtts > 0){
            for (Integer i = 0; i < numAtts; i++){ 

                Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
                efa.setFileName(allAttachment[i].Name);
                efa.setBody(allAttachment[i].Body);
                efa.setContentType(allAttachment[i].ContentType);
                efaList.add( efa );
            }
    }


    email.setSubject( subject );
    email.setToAddresses( 'test@test.com' );
    email.setPlainTextBody( body );
    if(numAtts > 0){
    email.setFileAttachments(efaList );
    }

    // Sends the email 
    Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
```

try like above code.

This is your updated code below

```
List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> efaList = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();

PageReference pdf = Page.CompIncidentTransactionsAttachment;
pdf.getParameters().put('Ids',Ids ); //
pdf.setRedirect(true);//false

Blob b = pdf.getContent();
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();

fa.setFileName('ComplianceIncidentReport.pdf');
efa.setBody(b);                   
efaList.add(efa);  // add into a list


PageReference pdf1 = Page.CompIncidentTransactionsAttachmentSample;
pdf1.getParameters().put('Ids',Ids ); //
pdf1.setRedirect(true);//false

Blob b1 = pdf1.getContent();
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa1 = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();

efa1.setFileName('SampleIncidentReport.pdf');
efa1.setBody(b1);

efaList.add(efa1); // add into a list   

email.setFileAttachments(efaList);
```